# How add and subtract a vector from a data frame row wise in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I want to subtract corresponding elements from each row in a df from a vector.

```
> test
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0

Expected output:

> test + c(3,4)

  A B
1 3 4
2 3 4
3 3 4

Actual output:

  A B
1 3 4
2 4 3
3 3 4
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will give what you want although it's a little tricky.
`t(t(test) + c(3,4))`

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Here `each = 3` is the `nrow` of `test`

```
test + rep(c(3,4), each = 3)
```

You can imagine the dataframe `test` is transformed into a vector `c(A,B)` firstly when it puls a vector `c(3,4)`. Because `c(3,4)` is shorter than `c(A,B)`, it will be extened to a same size vector.